# BigQuery - Where can I find the error stream?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have uploaded a CSV file with 300K rows from GCS to BigQuery, and received the following error:

[image: error_image]

**Where can I find the error stream?**

I've changed the create table configuration to allow 4000 errors and it worked, so it must be a problem with the 3894 rows in the message, but this error message does not tell me much about which rows or why.

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'm finally managed to see the error stream by running the following command in the terminal:

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j <JobID>
```

It returns a JSON with more details.
In my case it was:

```
"message": "Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '16.66666666666667' as int for field Course_Percentage (position 46) starting at location 1717164"
```

Comment: I had one job with 1k+ badRecords, but only shows 5 items from status.error[]. How could I view all the errors for other bad records?

Comment: What is JobID here?

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to click on `Job History` in the BigQuery UI, then click the failed load job. I tried loading an invalid CSV file just now, and the errors that I see are:

```
Errors:
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details. (error code: invalid)
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 columns. (error code: invalid)
```

The first one is just a generic message indicating the failure, but the second error (from the "error stream") is the one that provides more context for the failure, namely `CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 columns`.

Edit: given a job ID, you can also use the BigQuery CLI to see complete information about the failure. You would use:

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j <job ID>
```

Comment: @Thanks Elliot but I see only one row as I posted. It has the number of the row but it does not show the reason for the error.

Comment: Same here Elliot. In the `Job Details` I simply find this error: `Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.`

Comment: I edited my answer, and I realized that Amy added one a while back too, showing how to use the CLI to print complete job information.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard How does Bigquery calculate the position in the CSV file? I get error saying its at position 482. But when when upload the table with just 5 rows (480-484), it does not throw error

Comment: I'm no longer with the BigQuery team (I moved to Snowflake)

Answer (score 7):

Using python client it's

```
from google.api_core.exceptions import BadRequest

job = client.load_table_from_file(*args, **kwargs)
try:
    result = job.result()
except BadRequest as ex:

    for err in ex.errors:
        print(err)
    raise
    # or alternatively
    # job.errors
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be printing anything more for us when using it in Jupyter. Ideas?

Comment: In my case `job.errors` contained the basic message but also contained a more detailed message about what was wrong with my CSV. The exception didn't have as much detail. So I'd recommend `job.errors`

Answer (score 7):

You could also just do.

```
try:
    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
except ClientError as e:
    print(load_job.errors)
    raise e
```

This will print the errors to screen or you could log them etc.

Comment: This is a really great answer. I was using Apache beam and got the same error, I thought it was related to Beam. Never thought it is bigquery load job into which I have to check for the errors. Now I can check it in python itself.

Answer (score 1):

Following the rest of the answers, you could also see this information in the GCP logs (Stackdriver) tool.

But It might happen that this does not answer your question. It seems like there are detailed errors (such as the one Elliot found) and more imprecise ones. Which gives you no description at all independently of the UI you're using to explore it.

Comment: Right now I'm reading _by hand_ a gigabyte CSV because Google Cloud doesn't know how to spot the error. Or even better, It doesn't want to show it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error while using python client for uploading to bigquery, you can use below code for listing all the errors.

```
for error in job.errors:
    print(error)
```

This will list all the errors encountered when you ran the bigquery job.