# Get failed files' name while loading wildcard path

Tags: python, google-bigquery

My load job loads "folder\*" to bigquery,

My caller is below, is there any field in load_job I can extract the failure files?

```
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    ["gs://{}/{}*".format(table["project_id"], p) for p in data["prefixes"]],
    dataset_ref.table(table_id),
    job_config=job_config,
    job_id_prefix="direct_{}_{}".format(table["schema"], 
table["table"]),
)  # API request
```

Comment: it's not a dup question

Comment: ok. it might be not a duplicate now - after you updated it :o)

Comment: so I reopened it. meantime - I still believe you can find answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52100812/5221944

Comment: I'd like to get the failure files then I can exclude them in next load.

Comment: i see. hopefully someone will answer your question. thank you for correcting me marking this question as a dup

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports "all or nothing" approach while loading data i.e it will either load all the data present in your input files or it will load nothing in case of an error.Since you are using wildcard to load multiple files, even if it encounters loading error for a particular file, it will not load any of the data.

You may want to configure different load jobs for different multiple files to achieve your goal

Further references

[Load Job quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs)