# Accessing csv uploading error collection on Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a super beginner with big query.

So, I've managed to store a csv into Google Data Storage, created a table, it returned some erros and I would like to check those errors.

I've seen in some resources about that, such as:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

[BigQuery - Where can I find the error stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100812/bigquery-where-can-i-find-the-error-stream)

I understood I should run this command in the terminal:
`bq --format=prettyjson show -j <JobID>`

However, when I run that in my root terminal I get this:
`-bash: bq: command not found`

When I run that in the big query terminal in https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery I get:
`Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "bq" at [1:1]`

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing `bq` binary installed in your visitor machine, this error: `bq: command not found` reflects my presumption.

Assuming that `bq` command line executor is a part of [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs) tools set:

> **Google Cloud SDK** is a set of tools that you can use to manage resources and applications hosted on Google Cloud Platform. These
>   include the `gcloud`, `gsutil`, and `bq` command line tools.

You have to install Google Cloud SDK on your client machine in order to leverage command line managing tools, if you are not using GCP [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs), where all the necessary SDK components are already pre-installed and up to date.

Generally [BigQuery web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui) graphical interface designed for running SQL queries based on [*DDL*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) and [*DML*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) statements, but useless for executing any kind of command line utils.

Comment: Tks for that. Installed the SDK ("Big Query Command Line Tool" is marked as installed, if I run /google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud it shows a lot of options) however bq command is still not found. Am I missing something?

Comment: Then I would definitely check Google SDK component statuses: `$ gcloud components list`. If `bq `  binary is installed, then probably you need certainly locate it, like `$ whereis bq` to fetch the exact path holder.