# Get error/notification when cloud function fails to upload file into BQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I created a cloud function that:

*Whenever a new file is uploaded into the google storage bucket, Function gets triggered and uploads that into bigquery*

The function is running smoothly but I have a question. Another person uploads CSV into the bucket and I assured her the data will be pushed into BigQuery straightaway. How I can get informed whenever an upload fails? (She may upload hundreds of files per day)

If I open the bucket is there any way to understand which file is uploaded and which failed?

Comment: Can you check this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52100812/18265570)?

Comment: no, thank you Roopa