# How can I access errors[] collection after transfer failed?

Tags: google-bigquery, transfer, data-transfer, error-reporting, google-cloud-shell

may I ask some help about accessing detailed error log for failed transfer in BigQuery?

I have this message in the transfer run details (some data is altered to keep anonymity):

Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 610; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://balbal/asdaf-2413-b40a-582429aeca8c/65ddb1c3-qwertz-24058881afd4/whatever-2_20240302010612.json; JobID: 306617459295:bqts_65e10910-14223bc9779a

- In the LogsExplorer I can not found any errors[] collection.
- I tried to get the content in CloudShell with bq --format=prettyjson show -j  where I used the whole JobID which is described above.
- I tried to load the gs:// address, replacing the gs:// protocll to https://storage.googleapis.com/ but I got access denied response.

So how can I access the content of the gs://balbal/asdaf-2413-b40a-582429aeca8c/65ddb1c3-qwertz-24058881afd4/whatever-2_20240302010612.json?

Thank you for your help in advance,
Sandor

Comment: Is the JSON file a line-delimited JSON? Please check also
`SELECT   * FROM   region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`

Comment: This JSON files are exported from Matomo and structured with Python to be a good format for BigQuery. At night our script makes 60-70 pcs of JSON files, each has 1000 line of JSON. I tried to upload to BigQuery with the new table create function and went well, but at night in the second file at row 610 there is something, which breaks the transfer. I thought I can access an error log, which tells me exactly what was the problem at line 610. Is this file the error report or I misunderstand something? gs://balbal/asdaf-2413-b40a-582429aeca8c/65ddb1c3-qwertz-24058881afd4/whateve.....

Comment: The file is the data you want to import. Please take a look at line 610. Is the deept too much, special characters. You can download using  "cloud shell" and input `gsutil cp gs://balbal/asdaf-2413-b40a-582429aeca8c/65ddb1c3-qwertz-24058881afd4/whatever-2_20240302010612.json . ` Then download over the menu.

Comment: I checked the original file, cannot see anything extraordinary in line 610. Where can I access the error [] collection in the CloudConsole?

Comment: This is written here [BigQuery - Where can I find the error stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100812/bigquery-where-can-i-find-the-error-stream)  Please use the cloud shell and run `bq show -j <JobID>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery - Where can I find the error stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100812/bigquery-where-can-i-find-the-error-stream)